# How to sort by the date field of the queried result?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am a newbie in javascript and MongoDB technologies. I'm trying to query a "Businesses" collection based on some conditions(using field and value). I need to sort the queried results using the date field(CreateDate). Could you please assist me? Thanks in advance for your help!:)
[[Screenshot of my code attached here]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3RTT.png)

Please note: The value in CreateDate field is stored as a string in YYYY-MM-DD format i.e 2017-04-01.

I got an error message saying

> "Cannot read property 'sort' of undefined"

when I tried to execute the following code:

CODE:

```
exports.readDocument = function(collection, uniqueKey, field, value, callback) {

    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
        assert.equal(null, err);
        db.collection("Businesses").find({
                "Id": uniqueKey
            }, {
                [field]: value,
                _id: 0
            },
            function(err, result) {
                if (result) {
                    result.toArray(function(err, items) {
                        console.log("toArray", items, err);
                    });
                    callback(true);
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
            }).sort({
            "Created Date": -1
        });
        db.close();
    });
};
```

Comment: you can sort using db.model.find().sort()

Comment: please add the code in text form to the question. you may have a look here, too: [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that name of field("Created Date") you are using in your query is same as that of used in Documents.Also it's best to stick with lowercase alphanumeric with underscores as field names.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the database name is correct. 
Also ensure you are getting the results as expected before sorting.
I highly doubt that the result is null, thats why you receive the error "undefined" object.

Answer (score 0):

i think your syntax is wrong here. your syntax should be like this

```
collection.find().sort({datefield: -1}, function(err, cursor){...});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection("Businesses").find({
                "Id": uniqueKey
            }, {
                [field]: value,
                _id: 0
            }).sort({"Created Date": -1}).exec(function(err, result) {
                if (result) {
                    result.toArray(function(err, items) {
                        console.log("toArray", items, err);
                    });
                    callback(true);
                } else {
                    callback(false);
                }
            })
```

Try this form mongoose driver.